# Data is changed when serial communication between Rasp PI 3 and Windows

Tags: python, serial-port, gpio, raspberry-pi3

I tested serial communication between Rasp PI 3 and Windows PC using python 3.X.
The received data was not same with the sent data. 
The source code and running environment of Windows PC were trustful.
I thought something(Source or configuration) of Raspi PI was wrong.

Please let me know the reason and how to solve it.

This is the code of Windows PC(receiver)

```
import time
import serial
import binascii

port = serial.Serial("COM4", baudrate=9600, timeout=0.5)

while True:
    rcv = port.read(100)
    s = bytearray(rcv)
    for c in s:
        print(hex(c))
    time.sleep(1)
```

As for Raspi PI 3, the configuration is following.

1. Serial lines of PC(COM4) were linked at each GPIO No 6,8,10(GND,TxD,RxD of GPIO slot).
2. 1 line was added in config.txt

   dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt

This is the source code of Raspi PI 3(sender)

```
import time
import serial

sp = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600, timeout=0.5)
sp.write(b'\xAA')
```

These are tested results(sent data and received data table).

send   :  receive

```
A9 : 2B 00
AA : 15 00
AB : 2A 00
AC : 0A 00
AD : 29 00
AE : 14 00
AF : 28 00
AA AA : 95 15 00
```

[DIDWEV:]20170216.2318.D005.K0.01

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply connect RS232 interface signals directly to your Pi GPIO. RS232 is in the range +/-12V. GPIO pins are in the range 0-3.3V, and there is a logic invert needed too. You need an RS232<>Pi level conversion to connect a conventional PC 9- or 25-pin D type RS232 interface to a Pi. Also you are risking blowing up the Pi or GPIO pins, they aren't designed for input voltages above 3.3V or below 0V.